# Check if addObserver for keyPath is assigned

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

I have an avplayer to play audio and I add an observer when the audio starts

```
 audioPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Is there a way that I can run a check in one of my functions to see if the observer exists or nil. If it exists, I can remove it. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no API to see if an observer exists or not. You need to keep track of whether you added the observer or not.

Comment: I see. Thank you